# Call function in function arguments

Tags: function

I have a function, we'll call it `funcA` that returns an object. I want to pass that object to `funcB`. Can I do this?

```
funcB(funcA());
```

so that `funcA()` is called first and the results are passed to `funcB()`?

Comment: Anyone else think this would be quicker to test than to post the question?

Comment: What the hell was i thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it helps, Yisroel, you can think of the object returned "replaces" the function in-place. So, after funcA() is executed, it is "replaced" by the returned value and passed into funcB().

Generally, though, you wouldn't want to do nesting functions like this for more than 3 levels. If it starts to become unreadable, store the object into a variable and passing this variable into the next function can make your code much more readable.

So the answer is yes, as everyone else pointed out.

Comment: actually, doing this is a code smell and though I have done it before, I would recommend against doing this at all, let alone for 3 levels (?!)

Comment: Sometimes it can be readable. i.e. Python 3:  `print(sum(len(getLines()))`

Comment: Darko, why would you recommend against this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with this, have you tried any sample?

It should work fine.

If you have faced any specific issue please post it.

If you want to pass the funcA as a parameter to funB then you have to call funcB as funcB(funcA)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The parameters to the function are expressions which are evaluated before the expression value is passed to the function. An expression can of course be a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work as you want.  `funcB(funcA())` calls `funcA()` and passes the result to `funcB()`

Perhaps you were concerned that it would pass the *function* `funcA` to `funcB()`?  For that, the syntax would be `funcB(funcA)`